# Sub Category Drop Down Top Menu in Magento

Tags: php, magento, navigation

With my limited knowledge of Magento and PHP I have found myself possibly on track but still missing the mark and hope someone can help me.

I currently have 4 categories (fibre optics, networking, test and measure, promotions) nested in the root category. The root category is a drop down menu item named 'products' in the main navigation.

e.g. Home | Products | Clarence | Contact Us

I would like to change this so that these 4 categories are displayed in the main navigation and their child categories are displayed as a drop down menu on rollover.

e.g. Home | Fibre Optics | Networking | Test and Measure | Promotions | Contact Us

I have tried editing the top.phtml file to display this, however I cannot nut it out.

Is anyone able to help me with this, or be able to point me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something like this. In your case, make 'Product' Category as sub-category of the 'Default Category'. Add the other categories like fibre optics, networking, etc. under sub-category of 'Products'.

Now, edit in your app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml. Include your new menu in it : Ex:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><?php echo $_menu ?></li>   
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>contacts"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
</ul>
```

Hope you got a clue now....

Well, if you have the menu to be in the following way:
e.g. Home | Fibre Optics | Networking | Test and Measure | Promotions | Contact Us

change the 'Default Category' as 'Product' and  Fibre Optics, Networking, etc as sub-categoies. I am not sure, changing the name of Default Category name is the correct way, but this will work..

Comment: Thank you so much! Pointed me in the right direction indeed!!